# This key is not authorized for this service

Tags: api, mapquest

We have been using the same key for over a month now and we just notice a few days ago that it is no longer working. We are having trouble searching for answers on the web, we hope someone here can enlighten us about this problem. Thanks!
Here is the full error:

> This key is not authorized for this service. If you do not have a key,
>   you can obtain a free key by registering at
>   http://developer.mapquest.com.

Answer (score 4):

There were changes in the licensing structure [that were announced late last year](http://devblog.mapquest.com/2014/11/17/are-you-a-community-edition-licensed-data-user/). Are you using your key with the correct service?  The Free & Open keys work with the [Free & Open APIs and SDKs](http://developer.mapquest.com/web/products/open) hosted on the open.mapquestapi.com subdomain.  For instance, if you are calling the Free & Open Geocoding API, you would want to be calling this URL: http://open.mapquestapi.com/geocoding/v1/address?key=YOUR-KEY-HERE